# How to send XML messages to web services

Tags: xml, visual-studio

I have created a form web site in Visual Studio. I want to send an XML message with the data of the form to another web service. How would I do this?

(I'm sorry if my question is too easy, I'm just doing this exercise for my university and I haven't worked on web services before!)

Comment: My exercise is to create a web service with a web form in visual studio.When the user completes the form, he would send the data of the form to a web service B with xml message(Web Service B will be created out of visual studio,in php or another programminh language)

Comment: Take a look at the HttpWebRequest class (here are examples: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/httpwebrequest_response.aspx or http://netomatix.com/Development/XmlWebRequest.aspx), give it a shot, and then post your code for us to help you out.  We don't write code to do people's homework for them.

Comment: thanks for your rapid answer!i read the first website you pasted and i have a small question!I have created the project that the article prompts me to do.Now,i have also created a WebSite for my university project.How i will connect them?thanks again!!(i didnt asked for you to do my homework,please dont be rude!i just asked for a tutorial,like the one you gave me!)

Comment: I didn't mean to be rude, but "Any code should be welcome" sounds like "please write some code for me".  Anyway, you'll want to modify the code to allow you to pass in a string that can be POSTed as part of the request (see the second example for how that works), and then in the code-behind of your web page, you turn the submitted form data into XML, and call the CreateWebRequest method to send a request, passing in the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web-services are always called with XML messages.  What I'm not sure from your question is whether you are meant to get Visual Studio to auto-generate a web-service proxy (by adding a web-reference) in your web-forms project, or if you need to create and post the XML to the web-service over HTTP yourself explicitly.

In the first case you need to add a web-reference to your project and point it at the URL of the service you need to call.  You can then interact with this as if it is a method within your project.  The nuts and bolts of your call being converted to XML and suchlike is hidden from you in this instance.  The following step by step guide is an example: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webservices/WebServiceConsumer.aspx

The alternative is that you need to build the SOAP / XML message yourself and perform an HTTP web request to post the XML content to the web-service.  This is a lower level task, but would give a better understanding of the mechanics of what is actually taking place when the call is performed.